# ArrayList vs. Vectors in Java if thread safety isn't a concern

Tags: java, performance, collections

Is there really that much of a difference between the performance of `Vector` and `ArrayList`?  Is it good practice to use ArrayLists at all times when thread safety isn't an issue?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Vector originates back from the pre-Collections API days, and have been retrofitted since to be a part of it. From what I've read, the reason it is not deprecated is because the core API depends on it.

ArrayList was written from scratch as a part of the Collections API and as such should be used unless you need to support Java versions down to 1.2.

If you need a thread-safe ArrayList, you can use the static factory method `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<type>);` to generate your list.

Comment: Yep, use ArrayList unless you're targeting J2ME/pre 1.2 J2SE.

Comment: I agree; Vector is only for support of old JVMs. Even if you need concurrency, use java.util.concurrent collection or the appropriate Collections.synchronizedXXX wrapper, not Vector (Blechtor!).

Answer (score 15):

If thread safety is not an issue, `ArrayList` will be faster as it does not have to synchronize.  Although, you should always declare your variable as a `List` so that the implementation can be changed later as needed.

I prefer to handle my synchronization explicitly because a lot of operations require multiple calls.  For example:

```
if (!myList.isEmpty()) { 
    myList.get(0);
}
```

should be:

```
synchronized (myList) {
   if (!myList.isEmpty()) { 
       myList.get(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Relying on the synchnizedList wrapper is a common mistake to make in these multi-call situations and leads to hard to find bugs as you think you've done it correctly...

Comment: Yeah, there aren't many applications of synchronised lists without further external synchronisation. Swing text's Document has the same problem (some of the wild thread-safety claims have been removed in JDK7).

Answer (score 9):

If thread safety isn't an issue you should always use `ArrayList`. Vector has the overhead of synchronization and it has been shown that the performance differences between `ArrayList` and `Vector` are abysmal. You can google for a lot of performance benchmarks.

Here's one [Timing & Performance](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter12/timing.html).

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring synchronization, the main difference between `Vector` and `ArrayList` is that `Vector` is a resizable array (similar to a C++ STL Vector) and `ArrayList` is a List that happens to be backed by an array.

The difference manifests itself in the [setSize()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setSize(int)) method. There is no equivalent method in `ArrayList`. Some ex-C++ Java developers get hung up on this. There are a number of ***easy*** ways to work around it so it shouldn't be an issue.

Just don't make the mistake of telling a C++ developer that an `ArrayList` is the equivalent to a `std::vector`. You'll never hear the end of it.