# How to get two dimensional Vector properties (count of inner vectors, element count in each inner vector) in Java?

Tags: java, vector

I have String Vector of Vectors in Java called data. I can access this vector elements:

```
(Vector) data.get(i)).get(j);
```

How can i get count of inner vectors (i) and element count in each inner vector (j).

Comment: [`Vector.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#size())

Comment: Is your code multithreaded? If not, why aren't you using ArrayList?

Comment: Vector.size() is for i multipled by j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of inner vectors:

```
((Vector)data).size();
```

Number of elements of each inner vector:

```
for(Vector v : (Vector)data) {
    int nrElemsInCurrentInner = v.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Vector.size()` to get collection size. While this would solve your immediate problem:

```
int innerCount = ((Vector)data).size();
for (Object v: data) {
   int elementCount = ((Vector)v).size();
   ...
}
```

would suggest to use generics here to avoid casting:

```
int innerCount = data.size();
for (Vector v: data) {
   int elementCount = v.size();
   ...
}
```

Also `ArrayLists` are typically used now since the introduction of the Collections API in Java 2. See [ArrayLists vs Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300519/arraylist-vs-vectors-in-java-if-thread-safety-isnt-a-concern.)

Comment: Hello @Reimeus !! I have a question .. I have multidimensional Vector, on index[0] I have an array "[256, 222, 11813, 61, 61, 11813]" .. so how can we get index[0][2], without making loop ?